# PIA_INSTALL_FAIL during PeopleSoft Server Administration

Tags: webserver, weblogic, peoplesoft, pia, tuxedo

I'm following the online installation example (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ElSGLkprkY) to install PeopleSoft with PeopleTools on Windows 7 with SQLServer 2008 R2.

My PS and PT installation version differs from the online videos since I'm using most recent available versions:

- PeopleSoft HM 9.2
- PeopleTools 8.55
- Tuxedo 12.1.3.0.0 with VS2012
- WebLogic 12.1.3.0.0 64bit
- JDK 7u55 x64
- SQL Server 2008 R2

I could install each element with no error, excepted one VIEW during HC database creation (PS_EP_APPRMOB_PNDG), but I could re-create the view manually by slightly modifying the SQL query.

Now I'm trying to configure the Web (PIA) Server and I encounter an error while creating the domain. The piainstall_HC.log file contains following:

```
Tue Sep 20 09:48:32 CEST 2016:Starting PIA installation...
PS_HOME: c:\PT8.55
Install Action : CREATE_NEW_DOMAIN
Creating Domain...
Deploying Web Applications...
Deploying WebLogic Extension files...
Deploying PeopleSoft Site files...
Deploying PeopleSoft Site Doc files...
Completed.
PS_CFG_HOME: C:\PS_CFG_HOME
PIA_INSTALL_FAIL
```

After intensive googling, I found that some other people got a similar issue which was caused by a wrong version of the JDK: the JRockit jvm was required.

Of course I tried to use JRockit JDK 64bit, but I still get the same error. I also tried several other oracle JDK versions, among others the JDK 7u55 x64, which is provided with PeopleTools installation elements.

Unfortunately, I definitively get the same error and cannot find any other logfile which could give more information on the root cause.

Did someone experienced the same issue and could fix it ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could fix the issue.

It seems that my error was to install the wrong weblogic version: originally, I installed weblogic by using the "setup_fmw_12.1.3.0.0_ohs_win64.exe" installer which was provided with PeopleTools.

It appears that the other one (fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar) was expected. After installing this version (with "Coherence"), the domain could be created successfully.